# Is it possible to switch high speed USB data lines with a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, usb, differential

I'd like to programatically disconnect DATA lines on a USB device (while leaving the power lines active), and I know that USB data lines are a differential pair, which I have no previous experience with.

So the question is: is it enough to use a reasonable quality signal MOSFET (p-channel) to do so? This should work with high speed (480 Mbit/s) USB, and I've found a blog post which recommends using an analog switch ("like 74HC4066") for this purpose instead.

Comment: What disruption of functionality are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Two things, at first just the disconnection / reconnection of a device to be controlled by a MCU (i.e. as far as the host is concerned, that the device might just as well be unplugged / replugged, ignoring the power lines which will stay on), and in the future, possibly "multiplexing" of two devices, i.e. the MCU controls which one is presented to the host - but that's not the subject of this question.

Answer (score 3):

Won't work with a MOSFET picked at random, too much capacitance, too much chance for bad layout, etc.

Why not use a chip designed for this specific purpose?

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts3usb30.pdf

Comment: Good idea, but let's say I don't have the means to solder this SMD for prototyping...?

Comment: I haven't checked, but perhaps you could find this type of switches in packages like TSSOP?

Comment: @IvanVoras Prototyping USB without making a prototype PCB is a very bad idea at speeds of USB HS mode - 240++ MHz. Without carefully controlling impedance of the entire differential link, you likely will waste a lot of time chasing ghosts of reflections and intersymbol interference. Do a PCB prototype, with right real components. If you are validating/debugging some software regarding "surprise disconnect", there are devices already on the market that do this function for you.